# protection in CPUs with no protected mode

Tags: assembly, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I'm learning about the use of the mode bit, and the fact that certain CPUs like the Intel 8086 only operate in real mode. In a number of sources, I am told the following:

- The intel 8086 has no protected mode
- it can only use the first 1 MiB of memory

My question is, **why do they specify that only 1 MiB of memory is addressable?** Does this mean that there is unusable (but perhaps readable?) memory beyond that first MiB? **How is the memory beyond the 1st MiB used?** Is this the way that the CPU provides some manner of protection for processes like, say, the O.S.? Or does the CPU truly provide zero protection against accidental overwrites?

Comment: It is a memory *addressing* limitation. When the processor is running in real mode, it can use only the low 20 bits of its address bus, which mathematically means it is impossible for it to address more than 1 MB of memory. Furthermore, much less than this 1 MB is actually *usable*, given how memory is mapped on the IBM PC. Most of this information is available via Google; where have you looked?

Comment: look at the chip pinout and notice the number of address pins, as well as google and bitsavers to find the documentation.

Comment: as with any system (current ones are no exception) you can expand memory by swapping out sections, and that was happening in the 8086 days, a section of upper memory could be swapped by using a board you bought with extra memory on it.  I would like to see page 7, then you have a 64K chunk of memory at some address.  tell the board to switch to a different page, now you have a different 64K at that address.  So you could do some expansion but your address space is still 20 bits.

Comment: can do the same thing with older chips or chips with 16 bit address space, can add more memory by adding more bits and providing a window into that space or various windows.  not uncommon, sometimes built into the processor/chip sometimes would have to be done externally.  memory was expensive back then and programs were lean and mean so didnt really need that much memory for most things.

Comment: and no there is no reason for a protected mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 8086/8088 has no addressable memory beyond 1M. This is because it only has 20 address lines, and 2^20 is 1,048,576. So the range of addresses is between 0 (hex 00000) and 1,048,575 (hex FFFFF). As you correctly noted, this has nothing to do with "protected mode," since that doesn't exist on the 8086/8088 processors.

Older processors have less memory available: the 8080 has 16 address lines, for a total of 2^16, or 65,536 bytes of memory.

This is similar to saying "there is no way to express a number beyond 999 if you only have three (decimal) digits."

Comment: So there is virtually no protection against accidental overwrites then?

Comment: Not virtually - there is no protection at all. The assumption is that the programmer is careful :-)

Comment: @Devilius exactly no protection, when programming in assembly on old computers, any mistake in code often resulted into reset of the computer (or freeze in infinite loop), and you had to reload whole development tools + source (mind you, on 8 bit computers this alone often took about 5+ minutes in total). So you better did check your code 5 times before actually executing it...

Comment: @Devilius It is even worse than Ped7g is writing: In the 1980s there were even computers sold which could be permanently damaged by wrongly written programs.

Comment: Besides the physical limitation, 16-bit real mode has no way for software to generate an effective address wider than 20 bits.  16-bit x86 linear addresses are `segment * 16 + offset`, where segment and offset are both 16 bits.  (["big real" mode](http://wiki.osdev.org/Unreal_Mode) is a workaround where you switch to 32-bit protected mode and load a segment register with 32-bit base and limit before switching back to 16-bit mode, but that only works on a CPU that supports the full 32-bit mode in the first place, so even 286 is stuck with the 1MiB limit)